# Need to speed up processing a SpreadsheetGear IWorksheet

Tags: c#, optimization, datatable, spreadsheetgear

Ok, I have a spreadsheet with 11,500 rows, and 12 columns. It uploads fine, but processing it takes forever. We're using SpreadsheetGear, and what I'm doing right now is putting the data into a DataTable, and iterating over it. With a 300 row file, it takes approximately 8 seconds. This is approximately 37.5 rows per second, which seems incredibly slow. I *think* the problem is the conditionals or newing up a few of the classes within the processing method, because I switched to a string array and didn't really notice a performance difference. It may also be the method calls within the method.

I tried using Interop, and that didn't work. It was giving me an error that the Excel component of Interop wasn't registered on my machine. And since this will be on our web server, I don't want to add additional components to the server.

Ideally, they'd like to be able to process a 4 MB file (the 11,500 rows is just under this) in under 30 seconds, so I'm wondering if there's a tool or NuGet package I could use to quickly process this file. We have a piece of software that times out after 30 seconds, so the end user is getting an error message.

I haven't ruled out the conditionals being the problem, but I don't think that's really the issue. I'm just trying to figure out how to process this quickly.

I would post the code, but it's a LOT of code to post, and I think it's proprietary, and I didn't write it, I'm just editing it.

Comment: It would be helpful still if you posted a section of the relevant code which you have identified as the portion which is slow. Also what is slow? The SpreadsheetGear conversion of the excel to datatable? or the Iterating of the datatable?

Comment: The uploading and conversion are fine. It's the iterating of the datatable that's slow. I started processing a file about twenty minutes ago, and it's not finished yet. Granted, it's through Visual Studio, but still, that seems like a LONG time to process 11,500 rows in a DataTable.

Comment: what are you doing inside the iterations? It should take next to no time at all to just iterate the rows.

Comment: It's checking to see if certain cells are empty/null. It also gets current info from our DB, checks that object for null, does a DB update if not. It also checks for valid item numbers and valid items. If the product is valid, it checks a value and if true it does a little more processing with a nested loop, then looks up some stuff in the DB. Otherwise, it sets up a "controller", and processes some stuff that way. Then it gets products, and checks against them. And does more processing. Still doesn't seem like it should do 37 per second. That still seems slow.

Comment: Sounds like you are hitting your DB quite a bit in your loop, couldn't you just do a SELECT of all relevant items in the other DB tables into new DataTable objects and use those for comparisons and such in your loop so you can reduce the load on the server? Also, have you stepped through one of these iterations and made note of which pieces of the code are taking a long time to execute?

Comment: Stepping through it is my next step, but the last time I did, nothing really jumped out at me.

Comment: Also, do you have any of this wrapped in a try-catch? Any chance you are getting an exception in there?

Comment: Yes, the calling method has a try/catch. The method that processes the file is within the try/catch, so it should catch any exceptions. I tried using the Parallel.For() iterator also, but that kept giving me a null reference error in one of my other methods.

Comment: Well, without any of your code to go on, that's the best I can offer. I'd recommend seeing about doing one select for any table data you need and storing that in datatable obects so you don't have to continually query the DB, that could be part of the problem right there and also the step through should help uncover the long running pieces of the code.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan! I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: cool. Let me know how it goes, if I can help in some way, I will.

Comment: We have done a lot of work with big spreadsheets and spreadsheetgear. The rate limiting step has always been the load time. 1 - 2MB load reasonably efficiently and anything up to 5MB is manageable. After that the load time starts to get a too long.

Comment: In memory the SSgear operations are very quick. Are you opening and closing the spreadsheet inside an iteration?  That might be because the interaction is via a subroutine where the spreadsheet is opened and then disposed before returning. The other comment I would make is that it is much faster to copy the data to a DataTable, work with that and then paste it back to the spreadsheet when done.

Comment: It's not a matter of loading the data. That happens quickly even with the 4MB file. The problem is processing it and saving it to our DB. Iterating over the collection.